# PSU splicing and dicing

Tags: power-supply

Aside from capacity (and assuming there is plenty), is there any real reason why you cant splice in to existing Optic Drive/HDD power supply cabling to supply a graphics card? as far as I can tell most of these power sources are not managed by BIOS. This seems like a bit of a no brainer considering all the Molex adapters that have been made over the years but still. Here comes the curly part.....can I access power prior to the mainboard for the use by a graphics card??

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  The power supply is the "first" thing to come on, powering everything else.  All power available from the PSU is available as soon as it comes on.  You can power up the bare PSU if you simulate the power button closing.  You do have to watch the power limits on each branch, as each output has an individual limit.  Can you clarify where you think the MB might come into play?

Comment: Thanks fixer1234, I'm wondering if I take power from between the PSU and the mainboard to power a GPU then plug said GPU into PCIe slot on the mainboard if it wont cause a system crash (or worse) because the power being supplied to the graphic's card has not been appropriated by BIOS at boot........

Comment: Power isn't appropriated or directed by the BIOS, it's either there at the PSU output connection or it isn't.  You need to look at the total power requirement you're trying to supply from each PSU output branch.  Don't exceed the capacity of any output, or the total capacity of the PSU.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can.  However, there is no need as there [adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0032MT0OUk1) from 4 pin molex to 6 and 8 ping connectors on the market.

Comment: Thanks Keltari, I have revised the question slightly. Also there are no existing Molex connector's, hence the desire to access power elsewhere

Comment: @GavTownsend so get a molex splitter - https://www.amazon.com/Computer-Molex-Power-Supply-Splitter/dp/B001PI9AAC

Comment: SATA to PCIe adapters also exist if your power supply only has SATA connectors.